# How I can draw each corner of each face of a cube in a diferent color?

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm quite a rookie in GLSL and I've been struggling to try to find a way to color all the vertices of a cube in different color. Each face has 4 vertices and a cube has 6 faces, so 6 * 4 = 24. But I can only draw 1 color per corner.

Vertex Shader:

```c
#version 330

uniform mat4 u_m_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_vp_matrix;

layout (location=0) in vec3 a_position;
layout (location=1) in vec3 a_normal;

out vec3 normal;

void main()
{
    normal = a_position;
    gl_Position = u_vp_matrix * u_m_matrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
#version 330

in vec3 normal;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    fragColor = vec4(normal, 1.0);
 }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You have to be more specific. What do you want to achieve? *"How draw all vertices of a cube in a different color?"* - The vertices are at the corners of the cube. All the corners have different colors, haven't they?

Comment: I need to paint all verctices in different color. Each face have 4 vertives so 4 * 6 = 24 colors.

Comment: If I put normal = a_normal then only 3 faces are painted. Thanks for the help

Comment: _each face have 4 vertices_ (Correct!), _and a cube have 6 faces_ (Correct again!), _so 6 * 4 = 24._ (Now let me stop you, a cube has 8 vertices, each face shares 2 vertices with another face)

Comment: @jalsh each face shares *every* vertex with another face in any closed model.

Comment: Not to be blunt, but where are you getting this 24 number from? Cubes have eight distinct vertices. Your sample image already draws each one in distinct color.

Comment: @3Dave, yep, I meant 2 vertices a time, with another face, eventually all vertices will be shared, thanks for the note

Comment: Yes, that right but I need to color echar corner with 4 colors different so I need 24 colors. Sorry if I dont explain that correct :/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to color each face in a different color and you want to find a in-shader solution, the a possibility would be to color the fragments of the cube, dependent on the component of the vertex coordinate with the maximum amount.

Pass the vertex coordinate to the fragment shader:

```c
#version 330

uniform mat4 u_m_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_vp_matrix;

layout (location=0) in vec3 a_position;
//layout (location=1) in vec3 a_normal;

out vec3 vertPos;

void main()
{
    vertPos     = a_position;
    gl_Position = u_vp_matrix * u_m_matrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

Find the component of the vertex coordinate withe maximum absolut value and chose a color:

```c
#version 330

in vec3 vertPos;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    vec3 posAbs  = abs(vertPos);
    vec3 color   = step(posAbs.yzx, posAbs) * step(posAbs.zxy, posAbs); 
    color       += (1.0 - step(color.zxy * vertPos.zxy, vec3(0.0)));

    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

---

If the normal vectors are face normals, then there is even a simpler solution using the normal vectors:

Pass the normal vector to the fragment shader:

```c
#version 330

uniform mat4 u_m_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_vp_matrix;

layout (location=0) in vec3 a_position;
layout (location=1) in vec3 a_normal;

out vec3 normal;

void main()
{
    normal      = a_normal;
    gl_Position = u_vp_matrix * u_m_matrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

Compute the color dependent on the normal vector:

```c
#version 330

in vec3 normal;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    vec3 color = abs(normal.xyz) + max(normal.zxy, 0.0);
    fragColor  = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

---

> [...] so I need 24 colors. [...]

In that case I suggest the following solution.

```c
#version 330

in vec3 vertPos;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    vec3 posAbs = abs(vertPos);
    vec3 color  = (step(posAbs.yzx, posAbs) * step(posAbs.zxy, posAbs) +
                   step(0.0, vertPos.yzx)) * 0.5;
    fragColor   = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to color echar corner with 4 colors different so I need 24 colors. Sorry if I dont explain that correct :/

Comment: @Andre See the last section of the answer, which I've added right now.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer was super usefull! How can you make it in-vertex solution? I just need calculate that on the vertex shader and pass it to the fragment shader?
Thank you @Rabbid76

Comment: @Andre Sadly that does not work in vertex shader, because the amount of all the components of the vertices is 1 (at least the same) for all vertex coodinates. The trick in the fragment shader is that the amount of the components of `vertPos` is not equal, except exactly on the corners or edges, but that is negligible. Anyway the computation is not expensive and can be done per fragment with ease.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. Thank you so much for take your time to answer. You have helped me a lot